# Create or update a new record in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow where I have a screen to create a new record of a custom object and then navigate to a new screen with a custom lightning component. When I go back, pressing on previous, from the second screen to the first one, if I press the next button I want to update the record and not to create a new one. I created a decision step where I check if the record ID(of my first screen) exists or not and then decide to create or update the record, but nothing works and it creates a new record.

[image]

[image]

The OfferRequestID is created on Create Records Step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. I followed the solution that is described here: https://theaccidentaladmins.com/finding-lost-variables .
I created a field at object level, called 'Flow Interview Guide ID', where I can save the GUID of the flow. After my first screen and before create record step, I use a get record where I filter records that have at 'Flow Interview Guide ID' field the current flow ID. At the first time, this returns me NULL, so flow creates the record. At the 2nd screen when I press previous, the get records step returns me the record ID, so I can update it.

[image]

[image]